# Where the openstack machine images are stored?

Tags: cloud, cloud-computing, openstack, openstack-glance

In Openstack cloud whether the machine images are stored inside the database as a blob object or in filesystems?
And if images are getting stored in filesystem then which service take care of it, is it glance or swift?

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine image is a single file which contains a virtual disk that has a bootable operating system installed on it.
It is stored in filesystem.
Glance is the project which provides discovery, registration, and delivery services for disk images in OpenStack
For more details you can refer following documentation:
[OpenStack Docs: Glance’s documentation!](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/glance/)

Comment: Can't Glance use Swift as it's backend?